# Create a randomised list of element using a vector with 4 words

Tags: r, list, vector, combinations

I have a vector with 4 words :

```
v <- c("pevilo", "tufimi", "patoji", "nasola")
```

I would like to create a list that repeats 24 times each element, but with 2 conditions :

- cond 1 :  none of the element can be repeated twice a row (Example : `Cha , Cha`)
- cond 2 : The same pair of element cannot be repeated twice in a row (Example : `Cha, Adri, Cha, Adri`)

I have tried with this code in r :

```
v <-  c("pevilo","tufimi","patoji","nasola")
list2 <-  replicate(32, sample(v, 4, replace = FALSE))
```

But then I have 32 different vectors and the 2 conditions are sometimes violated.

Any ideas on how I could get this done using r ? Or has anyone a similar code ?

Comment: Please elaborte what `create a list that repeats 24 times each element,` means

Comment: `v -> c("pevilo", "tufimi", "patoji", "nasola")` is invalid R code and gives an error. Also you give an example vector `c("pevilo", "tufimi", "patoji", "nasola")` and later provide an explanation with `Adri, Cha,` which is confusing. Can you provide expected output for the data that you have shared?

Comment: @RonakShah edited, Q is clear, "cha, cha", "cha, adri" is just an example, replace it with any 2 of 4 words in vector v.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

v <- c("pevilo", "tufimi", "patoji", "nasola")

cond1_regex <-
  expand_grid(a = v) %>%
  mutate(b = a) %>%
  unite(u,  sep = ",") %>%
  pull(u) %>%
  paste(collapse = "|") %>%
  paste0("(", ., ")")

cond1_regex
#> [1] "(pevilo,pevilo|tufimi,tufimi|patoji,patoji|nasola,nasola)"

cond2_regex <-
  expand_grid(a = v, b = v) %>%
  mutate(c = a, d = b) %>%
  unite(u,  sep = ",") %>%
  pull(u) %>%
  paste(collapse = "|") %>%
  paste0("(", ., ")")

cond2_regex
#> [1] "(pevilo,pevilo,pevilo,pevilo|pevilo,tufimi,pevilo,tufimi|pevilo,patoji,pevilo,patoji|pevilo,nasola,pevilo,nasola|tufimi,pevilo,tufimi,pevilo|tufimi,tufimi,tufimi,tufimi|tufimi,patoji,tufimi,patoji|tufimi,nasola,tufimi,nasola|patoji,pevilo,patoji,pevilo|patoji,tufimi,patoji,tufimi|patoji,patoji,patoji,patoji|patoji,nasola,patoji,nasola|nasola,pevilo,nasola,pevilo|nasola,tufimi,nasola,tufimi|nasola,patoji,nasola,patoji|nasola,nasola,nasola,nasola)"

v %>%
  rep(24) %>%
  paste0(collapse = ",") %>%
  str_remove_all(cond1_regex) %>%
  str_remove_all(cond2_regex) %>%
  str_split(",") %>%
  purrr::simplify()
#>  [1] "pevilo" "tufimi" "patoji" "nasola" "pevilo" "tufimi" "patoji" "nasola"
#>  [9] "pevilo" "tufimi" "patoji" "nasola" "pevilo" "tufimi" "patoji" "nasola"
#> [17] "pevilo" "tufimi" "patoji" "nasola" "pevilo" "tufimi" "patoji" "nasola"
#> [25] "pevilo" "tufimi" "patoji" "nasola" "pevilo" "tufimi" "patoji" "nasola"
#> [33] "pevilo" "tufimi" "patoji" "nasola" "pevilo" "tufimi" "patoji" "nasola"
#> [41] "pevilo" "tufimi" "patoji" "nasola" "pevilo" "tufimi" "patoji" "nasola"
#> [49] "pevilo" "tufimi" "patoji" "nasola" "pevilo" "tufimi" "patoji" "nasola"
#> [57] "pevilo" "tufimi" "patoji" "nasola" "pevilo" "tufimi" "patoji" "nasola"
#> [65] "pevilo" "tufimi" "patoji" "nasola" "pevilo" "tufimi" "patoji" "nasola"
#> [73] "pevilo" "tufimi" "patoji" "nasola" "pevilo" "tufimi" "patoji" "nasola"
#> [81] "pevilo" "tufimi" "patoji" "nasola" "pevilo" "tufimi" "patoji" "nasola"
#> [89] "pevilo" "tufimi" "patoji" "nasola" "pevilo" "tufimi" "patoji" "nasola"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to make it work with a forced equal amount of 1, 2, 3, and 4. In order to achieve that you need some kind of algorithm to try many different iterations as most iterations will end up running out of numbers at the end of the list (for example only having a 4 remaining to fill in but it not meeting the conditions, forcing you to start over). I came up with something that does what you ask except for that.

```
vector <- c(1:4)

list2 <- list()
for (i in 1:(24*length(vector))) {
  lv1 <- max(unlist(list2[i-1]),0)
  lv2 <- max(unlist(list2[max(i-2, 0)]),0)
  lv3 <- max(unlist(list2[max(i-3, 0)]),0)
  if (lv3 == lv1 & lv1 != 0) {
    lv <- sample(setdiff(vector,c(lv2, lv1)), 1)
  } else {
    lv <- sample(setdiff(vector, lv1), 1)
  }
  list2 <- append(list2, lv)
}
```

What the loop does is check for every new value in the list what the previous values are. Next it checks if the value 3 items back is the same as the last value and if so the new value cannot be the same and the one 2 items back. In either case the new value cannot be the same as the last value. We achieve this by using `setdiff`

But you will see that it has it's limitations when we check for occurances:

```
library(dplyr)
as.data.frame(unlist(list2)) %>% group_by(unlist(list2)) %>% summarize(n())

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  `unlist(list2)` `n()`
            <int> <int>
1               1    27
2               2    23
3               3    21
4               4    25
```